# elastic search and logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am new to logstash and elastic search.I am using Windows and when I run in the command line through logstash to input data into the elastic .The entire command is "\Users\Documents\logstash-5.5.1\bin\logstash -f Users\Documents\data\logsash_cars.config". If I type this command, its showing that the pipeline main started and showing" Successfully started API endpoints" and then it just stays like that. The error being shown before displaying this is "No log4js configuration file found" 
The error is shown and its pic is in the link below.what to do next to move ahead??
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kd8JQ.png

Comment: Where is your `logstash-simple.conf` file located and are you in that directory?

Comment: The entire command is "\Users\Documents\logstash-5.5.1\bin\logstash -f Users\Documents\data\logsash_cars.config". If I type this command, its showing that the pipeline main started and showing" Successfuly started API endpoints" and then it just stays like that. The error being shown before displaying this is "No log4js configuration file found".

Comment: So you're all set. it works, now it just depends on what you're doing in your config, which we don't know if you don't show us

Comment: Update your question, it's more legible and easier for people to help you out

Comment: And also, describe what your problem is.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7Goh.png

Comment: I have edited the question and the above link shows whats inside config file.

Comment: You can ignore the Log4j error, it won't prevent Logstash from running. I think you're fine here.

Comment: But the data is not inputed . So how can I view them in Kibana

Comment: The path in your file input is wrong, you're missing the C: and you probably need to escape the backslashes as well

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked.:)

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out